# php script to get a dynamically loaded schedule of a website

Tags: php, curl, yii

I'm trying to make a php script which can take a specific tv channel schedule from a specific website written in Yii Framework. I'm trying to get the full HTML using php cURL but I can't find this section.

```
$curl = curl_init('http://port.hu/tv');
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'id=tvchannel-3&date=2017-02-05'); // for example
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
$content = curl_exec($curl);
echo $content;
```

I tried before with php file_get_contents with the same result. Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: (1) pretty sure this should be a `GET` not a `POST` (2) play around in Chrome Dev Tools to see what the site is doing to retrieve the schedule.  Check out: `http://port.hu/tvapi?channel_id%5B%5D=tvchannel-194&date=holnapi`

Comment: Yes! There was an API. That was the solution. Thanks. With the GET I would have the same problem because the dynamic AJAX content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot scrape directly from the website page, because looks like the website is using ajax (I guess) to load the data onto the page.
So what I did, I monitor the Network activity on the page using Chrome Developer Tools, and I found this API url:

> http://port.hu/tvapi?channel_id=tvchannel-3&i_datetime_from=2017-02-05&i_datetime_to=2017-02-10

It returned JSON strings, and the dev does not secure the API. So no need to scrape anymore, just load the JSON API directly.

Comment: Great!!! Thank you so much! I was looking for some API but I couldn't find it and then started to get the HTML. It works perfectly.